# Percentages in Sql cross tab

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd really appreciate some help please. I don't know if this is possible but I would like to add some percentages to my cross tab/pivot table below.

```
select

Isnull(SM.StatID, 'Total'),

count(case when ETT.description  = 'Equip1' then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Equip1',
count(case when ETT.description = 'Equip2' then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Equip2',
count(case when ETT.description = 'Equip3' then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Equip3',


from _INCIDENT as I
JOIN _EQUIP as EU on I.Identifier = EU.Identifier
JOIN _EquipTypeType as ETT on EU.EquipType = ETT.code
JOIN _StationMapping as SM on I.PartyStatId =  SM.CCStatID

group by statID with rollup
```

Current Output

```
    statID   Equip1    Equip2   Equip3    Total
    A          2         6        5        13
    B          4         3        4        11
    C          5         4        3        12
    Total      11        13       12       34
```

How I would like it to look

```
    statID      Equip1 |  %  | Equip2 |  %  |  Equip3  |  %  |  Total
    A            2     | 15% |    6   | 46% |    5     | 38% |   13
    B            4     | 36% |    3   | 27% |    4     | 36% |   11
    C            5     | 41% |    4   | 33% |    3     | 25% |   12
    Total        11               13             12              34
```

Failing that something like this would be good

```
    statID       Equip1   Equip2    Equip3    Total
    A              15%       46%      38%       13
    B              36%       27%      36%       11
    C              41%       33%      25%       12
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm really confused where are this percentages come from ???

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.... they are coming from the 'Total' Column.  You can ignore the 'total' row.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.... they are coming from the 'Total' Column.  You can ignore the 'total' row.   If you think of 'A' as a hospital, they use Equip1 (a certain type of equipment) 2 times  Equip2 6 times and Equip3 5 times giving a total of 13 different occasions these equipment are used.  2/13 *100 = 15%  6/13 *100 = 46%  etc

Comment: @whitz What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that you're using SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    statID
    , Equip1
    , CAST((Equip1 * 100.0 / Total) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%' as 'Equip1 %'
    , Equip2
    , CAST((Equip2 * 100.0 / Total) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%' as 'Equip2 %'
    , Equip3
    , CAST((Equip3 * 100.0 / Total) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%' as 'Equip3 %'
    , Total
FROM
    (SELECT Isnull(SM.StatID, 'Total') as 'statID'
        , count(case when ETT.description = 'Equip1' then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Equip1'
        , count(case when ETT.description = 'Equip2' then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Equip2'
        , count(case when ETT.description = 'Equip3' then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Equip3'
        , count(case when ETT.description IN ( 'Equip1', 'Equip2', 'Equip3') then I.Identifier else null end) as 'Total'
    FROM _INCIDENT AS I
    INNER JOIN _EQUIP AS EU
        ON I.Identifier = EU.Identifier
    INNER JOIN _EquipTypeType AS ETT
        ON EU.EquipType = ETT.code
    INNER JOIN _StationMapping AS SM
        ON I.PartyStatId = SM.CCStatID
    GROUP BY statID
    WITH rollup) result_set
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, have tried it and get this error

Comment: thank you for your reply, have tried it and get this error. Sorry if this is something obvious, still learning the ropes!                        Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @whitz Try it now, I made a small change on the first column. The error was generated because in that column you would normally display `SM.StatID` which is a **number**, but in case the value is `NULL` then you wanted to display `Total`, which is a **string**. This is not possible because all of the values in a column need to be of the same datatype. To resolve this I used a `CAST()` to convert everything to `NVARCHAR()` (thus is a string)

Comment: don't suppose anyone else can help with this please? getting as error message when running Radu's code   Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @whitz Forgot about this, try now please. Also, what datatype is 'SM.statID' ?

Comment: Hi Radu, same error again.  SM.StatId contains letters only.

Comment: actually, its not exactly the same error,  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ASH' to data type int.  I guess that kind of makes sense because SM.StatID isn't an integer?

Comment: @whitz Oh, you're right. I got my columns totally mixed up. I'll correct this shortly

Comment: @whitz I've updated my query. It should give you what you want now

Comment: This time it doesn't like this bit, saying invalid column names.  sorry to be a pain.       SELECT
    statID
    , Equip1
    , (Equip1 * 100.0 / Total) as '%'
    , Equip2
    , (Equip2 * 100.0 / Total) as '%'
    , Equip3
    , (Equip3 * 100.0 / Total) as '%'
    , Total

Comment: @whitz How about now?